# Can I concatenate within a directive declaration in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a form with an `ng-repeat` directive. I'm using `ng-show` to display validation error messages. I'm attempting to add a validation message within the `ng-repeat` directive, but I'm having trouble. This is what I have so far:

```
<form name="rentalApp" ng-controller="RentalAppCtrl">
  <label for="name">Full Name</label>
  <input id="name" name="name" ng-model="app.name">
  <div ng-show="rentalApp.name.$invalid">Please enter your name</div>

  <div ng-repeat="history in app.history">
    <label for="address{{ $index }}">Street Address</label>
    <input id="address{{ $index }}" name="address{{ $index }}" ng-model="history.address">
    <div ng-show="rentalApp.('address' + $index).$invalid">Please enter an address</div>
  </div>
</form>
```

As you can see, I am using the `$index` variable to make sure my IDs and names are unique.

In the rest of my form I'm doing something along the lines of:

```
<div ng-show="rentalApp.whatever.$invald">Error Message</div>
```

What I'm having trouble with is that within the `ng-repeat` directive, the indexes are dynamic. I've been fiddling around with this for a while, and the closest I think I've gotten to a solution is this line:

```
<div ng-show="rentalApp.('address' + $index).$invalid">Please enter an address</div>
```

However that doesn't work.

How can I properly concatenate the word "address" with the `$index` variable, to create a string along the lines of `address0`, which can then be used in my `ng-show` directive to determine if the form element is invalid? Or, alternatively, am I going about this completely wrong (not the "Angular way")?

**EDIT**

I'm looking at the `rentalApp` object from the console, and AngularJS is not evaluating the `name` attribute as I would expect. Specifically, the `rentalApp` object contains a `address{{ $index }}` object, instead of `address0`. So it looks like I can't use the expression `{{ $index }}` within the `name` attribute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATE**

I make a research and find out **it is not possible to give dynamic value to name** besides create a custom directive for it...

but there is a solution for you to validate dynamic form with `ng-form` directive for each individual `ng-repeat` element...

```
<div ng-repeat="history in app.history">
      <ng-form name="addressForm">
          <label>Street Address</label>
          <input name="address" ng-model="history.address" ng-required="true">
          <div ng-show="rentalApp['address' + $index].$invalid">Please enter an address</div>
          <span class="alert error" ng-show="addressForm.address.$invalid">Please enter an address</span>
      </ng-form>
</div>
```

and here is your [PLUNKER](http://plnkr.co/edit/mO0uxveNvB6PWLNi1Ljg?p=preview)...

Comment: That didn't quite do it. The `rentalApp` form is definitely an object full of objects. I've updated the question.

Answer (score -2):

Just put:

```
<input name="{{input.name}}"></input>
```